# Pandas merge not working due to a wrong type

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to merge two dataframes using

```
grouped_data = pd.merge(grouped_data, df['Pattern'].str[7:11]
                      ,how='left',left_on='Calc_DRILLING_Holes',
                      right_on='Calc_DRILLING_Holes')
```

But I get an error saying `can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

What could be the issue here. The original dataframe that I'm trying to merge to was created from a much larger dataset with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\cherp2\Desktop\test.csv")

data_drill = raw_data.query('Activity =="DRILL"')

grouped_data = data_drill.groupby([data_drill[
                                  'PeriodStartDate'].str[:10], 'Blast'])[
                                  'Calc_DRILLING_Holes'].sum().reset_index(
                                  ).sort_values('PeriodStartDate')
```

What do I need to change here to make it a regular normal dataframe?

If I try to convert either of them to a dataframe using `.to_frame()` I get an error saying that `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_frame'`

I'm so confused at to what kind of data type it is.

Comment: without posting the data, it is very difficult provide accurate answers. just error messages may get you the wrong answers.

Answer (score 2):

Both objects in a call to `pd.merge` need to be `DataFrame` objects.  Is `grouped_data` a `Series`?  If so, try promoting it to a `DataFrame` by passing `pd.DataFrame(grouped_data)` instead of just `grouped_data`.